# Formatting error within "cosinor" function in 'season' package

Tags: r

This should be simple, but the popular solutions aren't working for me...

I am trying to run a 'cosinor' function within the 'season' package (below)

```
cosinor(Ndata$Marsh ~ Ndata$Plot, type = 'daily', collection, data = 
Ndata, family = gaussian(), cycle=1, rescheck=TRUE, text = TRUE)
```

I am struggling with the date variable ("collection") within this function, as required by the type, 'daily' (R doc page: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/season/versions/0.3.8/topics/cosinor)

I know my date variable, "collection", needs to be in standard unambiguous format (%Y-%m-%d). It is, as far as I can tell (below)...

```
> collection
  [1] "2016-06-02" "2016-06-02" "2016-06-02" "2016-06-02" "2016-06-02" 
  "2016-06-02" "2016-06-02" "2016-06-02"
```

(...and so on, for more dates in same format. posted just first line)

I've played with it a lot, and I can't tell why this isn't acceptable by the function. Notably, I've tried fixing it using the "anydate" function within the "anytime" package to set the variable as an acceptable date format, and it still returns the same error message: "Error in charToDate(x): 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format"

I do get a different error if I mess with the "collection" variable (anything other than a date format tells me so, suggesting to me I need to indeed affix the "collection" variable to an acceptable format and that it is at the crux of the problem...less likely of another syntax error.

Thanks for any clarity anyone can offer on this!!
Best,
Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would remove the data from the regression equation, so:

```
cosinor(Marsh ~ Plot, type = 'daily', date = 'collection', data = 
Ndata, family = gaussian(), cycle=1, rescheck=TRUE, text = TRUE)
```

Is there any missing data for any of the important variables? That might have caused the issue. What does `summary(Ndata)` and `str(Ndata)` give?

Also the date variable needs to be in speech marks.

Comment: Thank you for the response, agbarnett!

I haven't identified any missing data in any of the descriptor variable. There are NA's for the response variable though (designated "NA"). 

I don't have enough characters allowed in this reply comment to post the output of summary and str. I'll email them to you though.

Thank You!!

Comment: Try putting the collection variable in single speech marks.

Answer (score 0):

agbarnett helped me figure out the issue on the side. For those that happen upon this later...

By reading in the data using a read.table() instead of read.csv, the glitch seems to have been cleared up. Probably something to do with my computer's configuration, maybe? Unsure, but try read.table() instead!

Thanks agbarnett!